# convert a cardview to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

similar type of questions has been asked several times, but I am still having a tough time to understand where the image is saved. I am using the accepted solution of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200535/how-to-convert-views-to-bitmaps).

I have a `cardview` that I want to convert to an image and share it(that's a different issue).
My cardview is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
......
android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cv_abtme"
        android:layout_width="368sp"
        android:layout_height="273dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/about_instagram_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        ....

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I am trying to convert it as:

```
public class AboutMeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_me);
        ImageButton cvbutton= findViewById(R.id.imageButton_abtme);


        cvbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getBitmapFromView(view);
                Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"Image Captured", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null)
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how it's working, as I can't see any image produced, but obviously no error.

So, the question is:

1. What is the path the image created?
2. Do I need some permission to save and access the jpg?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the path the image created?

Based on the code in your question, it is not saved anywhere. You did not write any code to save it. You created a `Bitmap` object, and that is it.

To save a `Bitmap` as an image file on disk, call `compress()`, specifying the image type and a `FileOutputStream` to where you want to save it.

Comment: ah..i thought so. But what is the utility of saving the bitmap then? is it viewable anyway?

Comment: @BaRud: "But what is the utility of saving the bitmap then?" -- I do not know what you mean, sorry. "is it viewable anyway?" -- um, you can display a `Bitmap` in an `ImageView`, if that is what you mean. A `Bitmap` is simply an in-memory representation of a bitmap, just as `String` is an in-memory representation of text.

Comment: In a different way, can I share the CardView directly using easyshare?

Comment: @BaRud: I do not know what "easyshare" is, sorry.

Comment: I meant this: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @BaRud: To use `ACTION_SEND`, you need to use a `content` `Uri` to pass things like images to the other app. A `content` `Uri` is backed by a `ContentProvider`. The simplest way for  you to have such a `ContentProvider` is to save your `Bitmap` to a file, then use `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code working fine.I hope might be helpful this code

here `xml` fiel for `cardView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
     xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/card_view"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_width="250dp"
     android:layout_height="250dp"
     card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/img_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here code to download cardview as a `jpeg` file

find cardview
        CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        loadView(cardView);

Load view

```
 public void loadView(CardView cardView){

    try {
        cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap =  loadBitmapFromView(cardView);
        cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        String mPath =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sid.jpg";

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new
                FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

get Bitmap from view

```
 public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    v.draw(c);

    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

cardview jpeg file save in ExternalStorage location with file name `sid.jpg`.

MyCompleted `Activity` class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    loadView(cardView);
}
public void loadView(CardView cardView){

    try {
        cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap =  loadBitmapFromView(cardView);
        cardView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        String mPath =
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sid.jpg";

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new
                FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.widthPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(dm.heightPixels, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(),
            v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    v.draw(c);

    return returnedBitmap;
}

}
```

Add premission on `manifest` file for save jpeg file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: followed this, but still no file. any idea where to search the file for?

Comment: @BaRud in your device external storage root directory.

Comment: Aha... Is there any way to put it in download dir, as i don't have any external storage.

Comment: Actually, there is file created in /Android/data/myapp.

Comment: @BaRud i have just updated my code please check its working fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Is it possible ro upload the complete activity?

Comment: means get completed activity bitmap ?

Comment: No no... I mean the complete code, including oncreate

Comment: logic says it should work, and I have just put an onclicklistner. But still there is no file created at /Android/myApp/data. Actually the data dir does not exist at all

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the view object of the button.
You've to inflate your layout into a view object then you've to pass that to your function.
This might help you.
[Create a Bitmap from a Layout/View before/without draw](http://android-crap.blogspot.com/2013/02/create-bitmap-from-layoutview.html)

Comment: Even though a link is useful as a reference, please consider improving your answer by, for instance, using concrete examples that will help the OP or by extracting, from the link, the relevant contents.