# converting CardView from RecyclerView to a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

I have a CardView (with multiple items like imageView, textView, Buttons) in a RecyclerView. I want to get bitmap from this cardview. I tried a simple method of converting cardView into bitmap ([convert a cardview to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935403/convert-a-cardview-to-bitmap/48935539#48935539)) but its not working properly. I only got the raw view of the card just like in xml without any updated items from a firebaseserver.

Comment: what do you mean with changed items from the server?

Comment: Code, please so we can actually know what is going on :)

Comment: @kingston i mean updated items

Answer (score 1):

CardView extend view, so you probably can convert it as any other view,
try to pass the CardView into that function:

```
  public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) 
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else 
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are probably taking the screenshot of view before it is fully inflated. Try adding a 2 second delay or implement this on layout listener of the card view